# Network setup issue with no connection between virtual machines

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, ping

I have the following network setup:

[image]

EDIT: NOTE: WARNING: In the above Windows1 should have the ip 192.168.137.1

The issue that i am having is that every machine can ping and connect to every other machine except:

QNX1 cannot ping QNX2.

I have had this exact setup working where Windows2 was a fedora machine, but Had to give that machine back to a work mate.

There are no firewalls turned on any of the machines in question.

I am not sure what is going on, does anyone have a suggestion about a debug path?

Ben

Comment: What is the host OS? What is the hypervisor? Does each host have a virtual switch bound to a physical NIC that's connected to the physical switch? Does each VM have a virtual NIC connected to the virtual switch?

Comment: @joeqwerty I am not sure what that all means, but the VM's have bridged network adapter set to auto DHCP. Windows1 is sharing the wireless internet connection and assigns the fedora, windows2 and QNX1/2 ips automatically. The VM's can connect and ping everything except each other. And everything else can ping and connect to the VMs.